# Manager Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

The Nautilus manager is good, but I think he needs supplements, despite many extensions. Could have the action open as root it, show how much storage is being used. For this what would be the best option to create a new file manager for Ubuntu with System Innovation face, or use the Nemo manager? I'm not a developer is only one question I do.

Comment: I am not sure this question is answerable in a concrete way. Might be better to ask this on a forum.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have tried to answer the question in a concrete way, because the required features already exist  in Nemo. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I would try Nemo first before trying to create a new file manager for Ubuntu, because Nemo already has the features that you are looking for. Nemo is a complete fork of Nautilus and its goal is to extend the Cinnamon user experience to desktop and file management. Nemo has features like: compact view, all desktop icons, etc. which are not available in the latest nautilus versions, Open in terminal and open as root, File operation progress while copy/move files shows percentage and details, Has nice GTK bookmarks management, up/forward/back and refresh buttons, Nice proper status bar, better search, better widgets and many more.

To show how much storage is being used in Nautilus, right-click any folder and select *Properties* -> *Basic* tab and look for the *Contents:* field, the third field from the top. There is probably a similar feature to show how much storage is being used in Nemo.